# How to resolve ruby gem conflict involving rake on mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I am attempting to run rake under Mac OSX and I am getting the below error.

```
$ rake --trace
rake aborted!
Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate releasy-0.2.2, because rake-10.3.2 conflicts with rake (~> 0.9.2.2)
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2112:in `raise_if_conflicts'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1280:in `activate'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:198:in `rescue in try_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:195:in `try_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `rescue in require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
/Users/Development/RUBY/rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

gem list --local displays

rake (10.3.2, 0.9.6, 0.9.2.2)

How would I resolve a conflict between the rake gem I installed and the rake gem that is deployed with OSX? Should I just delete the newest update or is there a way to specify in my rake file to use the newest version and ignore the conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to run `rake` from within a project that uses a `Gemfile`, try this:

```
bundle exec rake --trace
```

This will load up the version of rake required for the project, instead of one that could possibly conflict (like your OSX default /usr/bin/rake binary).

If the `bundle` command isn't found, do this:

```
gem install bundler
```

Also, if this is a recent Rails app, you can also use the provided binstubs instead like this:

```
bin/rake --trace
```

If none of this works, try using [RVM](https://rvm.io/), [Chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby), or [RBEnv](http://rbenv.org/) to manage your Ruby environments separately from the operating-system provided Ruby.

Comment: For the latter, it helps to have `./bin` in your PATH so that you can just run `rake`

Comment: @MusannifZahir Though I agree this is convenient, I would rather not do this for security reasons. What if I open a malicious directory with a `bin/ls` in it?